# Boost::Asio - read or read_until?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm learning to use Boost::Asio

I was wondering : when should I use read_until ? When should I use read ?

Is it better to specify the length of your data in a header at the beginning of your data buffer OR to use a delimiter with read_until ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One is not better than the other.

You use what your protocol requires.

Typically

- binary protocols specify the packet length up front (by sending it first)
- text protocols tend to structure information using delimiters (like `{ ... }` for JSON like grammars, or `\r\n` for SMTP/HTTP etc).

Naturally you'd use `read_until` for the latter